# Remember bash directory stack across sessions?

Tags: bash

Bash will remember command history across sessions, but not the directory stack created with `pushd`.  Is there any way to remember the directory stack as well?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, but please post it as an answer and not in your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the `dirs -p` output?
You could save it from your `.bash_logout` and sort-of re-load it with a minor script in the `.bash_login`

<sup>See more at [Directory Stack Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html) bash page.</sup>

Comment: I'd initially dismissed that idea, since if bash terminates abnormally, or if bash isn't a login shell, then that won't work.  But I could alias `pushd` and `popd` to dump `dirs -p` to a file on each use.

Comment: @MatthewCline its a good insight, although I wish this were part of default pushd/popd behavior (or configured somewhere). Ideally it would be paired with some sort of "terminal id" for reconfigurable sessions.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a way to determine which shell I'm in consistently across sessions: the environmental variable `SHELL_SESSION_ID`, which the KDE session manager supports for Konsole (not sure about other desktop environments).  With that said, the solution I put together based on user nik's answer:

In `.bashrc`, in the setup code for interactive shells, I added this:

```
# Don't remember directory stacks for subshells, just the top level
# shell.
if [[ -z "$BASH_SESSION_ID" ]]; then
    # Get bash-session the X Windows session manager, if possible.
    if [[ -n "$SHELL_SESSION_ID" ]]; then
        export BASH_SESSION_ID=$SHELL_SESSION_ID
    else
        export BASH_SESSION_ID="DEFAULT"
    fi
    .  ~/.bash_dirs
    load_dirs
fi
```

`BASH_SESSION_ID` is used rather than directly using `SHELL_SESSION_ID` so that for environments that don't have `SHELL_SESSION_ID`, something else can be used.

The contents of `.bash_dirs` is this:

```
_DIRS_DIRS=~/.dirs

# Silently make sure ~/.dirs exists
\mkdir -p $_DIRS_DIRS

_DIRS_FILE=$_DIRS_DIRS/$BASH_SESSION_ID

save_dirs() {
    \dirs -l -p > $_DIRS_FILE
}

load_dirs() {
    # Start out with a fresh directory stack.
    \dirs -c

    # Make sure there's at least an empty file.
    if [[ ! -f "$_DIRS_FILE" ]]; then
        touch $_DIRS_FILE
    fi

    # Start out in the directory we left off at
    for dir in $(cat $_DIRS_FILE) ; do
        \cd $dir  > /dev/null 2>&1

        # Just need the first line
        break
    done

    # Restore saved dir stack in reverse order.
    for dir in $(cat $_DIRS_FILE | tac) ; do
        # But don't duplicate the directory we left off at
        if [[ $PWD != $dir ]]; then
            \pushd -n $dir > /dev/null 2>&1
        fi
    done
}

# NOTE: aliases can't take parameters, so we have to alias to functions.

_dirs_pushd()
{
    \pushd "$@"
    save_dirs
}
alias pushd=_dirs_pushd

_dirs_popd()
{
    \popd "$@"
    save_dirs
}
alias popd=_dirs_popd

# In case 'dirs -c' is used.
_dirs_dirs()
{
    \dirs "$@"
    save_dirs
}
alias dirs=_dirs_dirs
```

Comment: Raw pastebin of the above `.bash_dirs` for command line download: http://pastebin.com/raw/FsAcG23N

Comment: For anyone wondering about the leading backslash ("\") on many of the commands above: it disregards any possible aliases and just executes the default command of that name.

Answer (score -1):

While this is not exactly what you are asking about, it may be handy to use `tmux` which basically allows to store, detach and reattach multiple terminal sessions (but also much more like splitting window etc) and thus "store working directories" for each context (session).

Some basic usage:

- `tmux` – create new tmux session, attach to it
- `ctrl+b d` – exit tmux session
- `tmux ls` – show list of tmux sessions
- each session has a name, when one uses `tmux`, the name is given as a number (least natural unoccupied), but one can also specify it: `tmux new-session -s reasonable_session_name`
- to enter a previously created session: `tmux a -t reasonable_session_name` (or `tmux a -t 1`)
- inside each tmux session, one can create "windows" (`ctrl+b c`) and switch between them (`ctrl+b window_number`). In a simple case, each window is separate terminal session
- inside each window, one can create stacked (horizontally and/or vertically) "panels" to have more than one terminal shown simultaneously
- ...